# How to set start and end row key HBASE

Tags: hadoop, hbase

If i have row keys like

```
a_c
b_c
j_f
f_d
d_c
```

I should get all the rows matching _c. How to set start and stop row key here . I am trying to get the scan result out of start and stop row key and not with rowfilter or other filter types.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own filter function if you don't want to use `RowFilter`. But I suggest you to use [PrefixFilter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/PrefixFilter.html) if you can't write your own filter function and don't want to use `RowFilter`

Example for Java:

```
byte[] prefixF= Bytes.toBytes("_c");
Scan scan = new Scan(prefixF));
PrefixFilter prefixFilter = new PrefixFilter(prefixF);
scan.addFilter(prefixFilter);
ResultScanner resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

Above code is equal to `hbase> scan 'YourTablename', { FILTER => "PrefixFilter('_c')"}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason i don't want to use any custom filter or even rowfilter is that all involves a full table scan. That is the reason i am trying to solve with start and stop row key. Is it possible to obtain the scan result with start and stop row key with some regex?

Comment: Scan function enables you to set `starRow` and `stopRow`: `Scan(byte[] startRow, byte[] stopRow)`
Create a Scan operation for the range of rows specified.
It also allows you to set `startRow` and `filter` that you should use [Filter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/Filter.html) class of hbase: `Scan(byte[] startRow, Filter filter) `. I think  can create a function that is forScan class with `startRow` and `stopRow` and inside the function, you should use regex(Pattern, Match to filter the result. If you find another solution, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hbase STARTROW and ENDROW filter. It basically scans data between the rowkey range (ENDROW excluded).

```
 scan 'table_name', {STARTROW=>"<start_row_key>", ENDROW=>"<end_row_key>"}
```